# Which is the bandwidth of an analog PAM (needed to design an amplifier)?

Tags: amplifier, frequency, signal-processing, bandwidth, signal-theory

in a university test, I've been asked to design an amplifier for the following signal:

$$s(t)=\left[\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}rect\left(\frac{t-t_i}{T}\right)\right]\cdot Acos\left(2\pi f_0t+\varphi\right)$$

with:

- t_i+1 - t_i = 100us;
- T = 200us;
- f0 = 50MHz;

It seems to me something like that:

[image]
[image]
[image]

In such a test it's written that the amplifier bandwidth must be sufficient enough to work with the previous signal. But I don't know how I can evaluate that bandwidth (the frequency range in which the Fourier transform is non-zero).

[Here it's stated that the bandwidth of a product of signals is the sum of their bandwidths](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4865/what-is-the-bandwidth-of-product-of-two-signals). So, if it's true, here we'd get the sum of the bandwidth of a sine wave (the single frequency f0) and that of a rectangular pulse train. The last one is a sort of square wave, which has in theory infinite bandwidth unless a finite rising and falling edge times are specified. In this case they are not specified by the text.

Can you help me on evaluating it or telling me how you would do it (for instance, considering only the first 2 harmonics of the rectangular pulse train etc)?

Comment: I think you are right in the sense that the Fourier transform would replicate the shifted signal over and over. But I suspect (I don't know) that they are asking about a band-limited case.

Comment: After modulation, find the spectrum of the modulated signal. For product of two signals, the resulting spectrum is the convolution of the individual spectra. Include as many harmonics as required to cover 90% (or any other number of your choice) of the power of the signal. This would be one thumb rule to find the bandwidth required.